# can we pass the activity handle inside the fragment so as communicate to activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am trying to alter the activity content from fragment. for that i want to pass the activity handle inside fragment and do the required changes.
If i can do that why there is more difficult way of interface etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `getActivity()` from the Fragment.
If you want to get your activity specifically you can cast it

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).someMethod()
```

This will tightly couple your Fragment to your activity and prevent you using the fragment in a different activity easily so be careful.

Also you need to be careful with lifecycles and such as a fragment can become detached from an activity causing a `NullPointerException` from time to time. So it is recommended to wrap this in a null check

Comment: Though this is a legit way, I would advise against it. It is always best to do the communication via an Interface